# Disabling the soundcard for a specific user

Tags: windows-xp, sound-card

Does anyone know how to disable the sound card when a particular user logs on to Windows XP?

My last pair of speakers was blown by an inconsiderate user and I want to disable the sound to the speakers only when a particular user logs on.

The PC has multiple users logged on (one of which is me).

Answer (score 3):

You can use Microsoft's [*devcon* utility](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;Q311272) to disable a driver from the command-line.  *devcon* is like a command-line Device Manager; you can list devices, enable them, disable them, etc.  See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/125032/how-can-i-manually-load-unload-a-driver-in-vista/125035#125035) for some basic examples.

With *devcon* and administrator privileges, you can create a script that disables the sound driver. Then set it as a login script for that user via the Group Policy editor.

You'd also need to create a re-enabling script -- either set as a logoff script for that user, or as a login script for everyone else.  If you don't, your users will have to reenable the soundcard manually.

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/15596/automatically-run-a-script-when-i-log-on-to-windows/15605#15605) (thanks, Ivo) for how to assign a login script to a user or group, as well as a handy scripting howto.

**Note**: This may not be enough; just because *devcon* disables a device doesn't mean the problem user can't just re-enable it from the Device Manager.  You'd have to restrict the account through other means to prevent that.