# Run application or script on Windows RDC connection

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008

I checked another thread [(*Automatically run a script when I log on to Windows*)](https://superuser.com/questions/15596/automatically-run-a-script-when-i-log-on-to-windows), but it did not solve my exact problem.

I need to run a script on when a connection is made **across my network** using Windows *Remote Desktop Connection*.

The thread listed above works for the **initial** login, however, if I don't log out (which is necessary for some processes running on my network), then it **won't run the script again** the next time someone connects to the system using remote desktop connection.  Previously we were using pcAnywhere to achieve this, however after running into some graphical issues with pcAnywhere, we have decided to move away from it to RDC.

Background: We need to have an email sent out anytime a connection is made to particular machines.  The login name will always be the same for those systems and we do not log off when closing the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge Windows does not provide a built-in method for running a program or script on *connection*, only log on. You'll need to find a program that registers with Windows (using [WTSRegisterSessionNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383841(VS.85).aspx)) and listens for the
[WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383828(VS.85).aspx) message.

A program that does the above will receive notifications from Windows about user logons, logoffs, connections, disconnections, and all of the events needed to launch a script at connection as well as log on.

Off the top of my head I don't know of any applications (other than pcAnywhere) that can do this.

Comment: This is just about 100% of what I need.  I was able to extend the wrapper in the page you provided quickly to verify it worked for my needs.  Now I need to get the name of the connecting machine and its current logged in user.  Do you know where to get that information off the top of your head?

Comment: Digging a little deeper, I found there is a wrapper already written for my needs.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.sessionchangedescription.aspx

Answer (score 9):

You can make a new scheduled task and define the trigger to "At the moment of a new connection to a user session"

Comment: "We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed."

Comment: @gparyani, this is all information I needed. No need for a bunch of screenshots, if you'd ask me.

Answer (score 4):

## Use trigger "On connection to user session"

*Note: I only noticed that the question is tagged "XP"/"Server2008". What's here may only work on Vista/2008R2 onwards.*

Windows task scheduler has a predefined trigger for that. It is called `On connection to user session`.

It also allows you to distinguish between users and between local or remote connections.

The default when creating this trigger: `Any user` and `Connection from remote computer`. This seems to be what you want, so you don't have to change that.

Screenshot here:
[image: Screenshot of trigger]

Source: Microsoft TechNet: [*Task Scheduler | Triggers*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748841) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/1B5uq#selection-1617.0-1619.1).)

### Further reading

When you export this task and then look inside the file, you will see that this a trigger of type `SessionStateChangeTrigger`:
[image: Trigger detail]
There is in depth documentation on MSDN:

- MSDN: [`SessionStateChangeTrigger object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382142) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/8SW6b).)
- MSDN: [`SessionStateChangeTrigger.StateChange property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382144) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/KihHw).)

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with programming in .net, you may want to look at [this thread over at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973802/detecting-remote-desktop-connection).

According to Steven A. Lowe:

> allegedly,
>
> [`System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.terminalserversession.aspx)
>   will be true for a remote desktop
>   session (or VNC session)

You may also be able to monitor for a connection on the RDP, which by default is TCP 3389.

Comment: While .TerminalServerSession should return true when a connection is established there is no event to fire. Additionally, when a user disconnects and the program is still running it will still return true for being run in a terminal server session and will have no knowledge when the user reconnects.