# Run task on reconnect to remote desktop (not login)

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, scheduled-tasks, connection

Is it possible to run a task when a user **reconnects** to a remote desktop session?

- Some software is running on a machine that cannot be run as service and must **always** run,
- but I also need to trigger some things **when a user reconnects** to the session.

Is this possible? I would really prefer not to have a scheduled task running once a minute...

Comment: Windows Vista and upwards only: [scheduled tasks can do that](http://superuser.com/a/1168691/389368).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open up the Options in the Remote Desktop connection dialog, you should see a tab named Programs.  You can specify the program you want to run, along with its start folder, on that dialog.  You can of course also save the settings in a file from the General tab.

Comment: I was really hoping for a solution on the remote machine, but this does answer the question. I *require* certain programs to run *on connect* but I cannot guarantee that with a client-side solution.

Comment: @boot13 I don't see such a tab. I see General, Display, Local Resources, Experience, and Advanced tabs but no Programs tab.

Comment: @FleetCommand That's weird. Are you on Windows XP?

Comment: @boot13 No. I am on Windows 10.

Comment: @FleetCommand Yup, it looks like Microsoft removed that tab from the RDP client in Windows 10. Add that to the list of things that suck in Windows 10. But this question was about Windows XP, which definitely has that tab.