# Set an autorun program for a Remote user

Tags: remote-desktop

On a Windows Server 2016 we have configured several Remote Users.

Using a Remote Desktop connection these users are connected to the server.

I want that when a specific remote user is logged in , a specific program should automatically run.

Is this possible ?

Comment: do these users ever login not-remotely? if not, you could schedule tasks for that user on login.

Comment: Is this a domain environment?

Comment: These users login only remotely. And this is not a domain environment.

Comment: so then why not use scheduled tasks? you just need to get the app to run anytime they login. whether its local or remote won't matter anymore because they won;t login locally

Comment: @FrankThomas I Think i need more information how to setup this. Can you give me some steps ?

Comment: See the Trigger > At Logon described here; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc748841(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN so you would create your task, give it actions, configure any properties you need, and use an At logon trigger to schedule.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run application or script on Windows RDC connection](https://superuser.com/questions/122908/run-application-or-script-on-windows-rdc-connection)