# Minimize all open windows afer lock screen

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

Is there a way to automatically minimize all open windows after I enter the password in the lock screen in windows 7/ windows 8?

Comment: I don't know about "automatically", but WindowsKey + D will minimize everything.

Comment: I know that @LilCodger but I want the automatic way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: See this question about running a script on login http://superuser.com/questions/15596/automatically-run-a-script-when-i-log-on-to-windows

Answer (score 1):

Use [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/SendKeys.htm) to send the Win+D command. Run it with the linked Script Logon way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) which could probably automate this for you with a little bit of easy coding. Alternatively, you could use Win+ hotkey to show the desktop.