# "DOS Devices" to directory (aka permanent SUBST) not honored after Windows 21H1 update

Tags: windows, drive-letter, device-mapper, subst, windows-10-v21h1

Previously, a device mapping had been established using `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices` to add an alias from `D:\` to `C:\Build`. This approach discussed in [the wikipedia SUBST article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUBST#Registry_(DOS_Devices)) and similar.

***After updating to Windows 21H1* this registry setting was removed<sup>1</sup>, and even after re-adding the setting, the "D:" device is *not* being enumerate in Explorer, powershell, or bash-git (mingw).**

After the installation the "DOS Devices" registry section has been updated<sup>1</sup> to add a the registry key shown below. However, this does not seem to take effect. *How can I restore this 'permanent subst' functionality to a directory target?*

```
Name   Value
D:     \\??\C:\Build
```

- <sup>1</sup> https://www.satsignal.eu/software/Win-10-notes.html notes that the "DOS Devices" are deleted and have to be manually added back (in Windows 10 build 2004). It makes no mention of this functionality being removed. I have re-added the DOS Devices entry back and the mapped drive is still not appearing.
- Using WinObj (from Winternals) shows the correct Name and Symbolic Link Target in `GLOBAL??` for "D:".
- The "C:\Build" directory exists with standard permissions (eg. SYSTEM full control, Authenticated Users all-but full control, Users with read access).
- This was an in-place update of Windows 10 to 21H1. The previous version was probably Windows 10 build 1909 and it was definitely not 20H2.
- Either `net use` or an equivalent is *not* an alternative solution in this case. The access *must* be an alias at the kernel/driver level to expose the underlying filesystem at full performance and features.

With the "DOS Devices" entry in Windows 21H1, the "D:" device is still somehow known to windows and cannot be used with the SUBST command even though it is not enumerated or otherwise accessible.

```
C:\Users\me>subst X: C:\Build

C:\Users\me>subst D: C:\Build
Invalid parameter - D:

C:\Users\me>D:
The system cannot find the drive specified.
```

Per a suggested answer, `New-PSDrive` has been attempted. However, this approach does not appear to be a suitable replacement for at least two reasons:

- Unlike `SUBST`, `New-PSDrive -Name "D" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "C:\Build"` is *not* enumerated by different programs in the same session. For example, no new "D:" drive will show up in Windows Explorer.
- `New-PSDrive .. -Persist` only works on networked filesystems (even if local). This is unsuitable for general usage due to reduced performance and reduced filesystem features.

Comment: you're doing it wrong. A `D:` drive shows in my explorer, even after restarts

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation that this works in 21H1 still (as expected). However, this still does not result in solving my issue. *Helpful* troubleshooting suggestions are welcome. I've included relevant information above, including the values used in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerShell's [`New-PSDrive`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-7.1) instead

```powershell
New-PSDrive -Name "D" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\localhost\c$\Build" -Persist
```

The `-Persist` option will make a permanent drive. You can also remove it to make a temporary drive just like `subst`, and then

- put the command into the [profile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.1) (run `notepad $PROFILE` to open it or create it if not available) to run it every time you start PowerShell, or
- add the command to task scheduler to [run at logon](https://superuser.com/q/15596/241386)/startup/whatever

Comment: Using a UNC path is *very slow and not the same thing at all* :-/ Both the "DOS Devices" and SUBST (which makes a local session entry of the same, I believe) are underlying kernel/driver mappings, not a round-about model through other [network] subsystems.

Comment: There is an error when using `-Persist` with a local path. Just tried `New-PSDrive -Name "D" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "C:\Build" -Persist` ; so not sure why not just use SUBST here (as `-Persist` is ineffective in context).

Comment: Also, *unlike SUBST*, this drive mounted with `New-PSDrive` is *not show enumerated in other programs*. That is, it can't be used Explorer or a different bash session; so not sure why not just use SUBST here (which is shared within the same session).

Comment: I suspect `New-PSDrive .. -Persist` is closer to `net use`, which is not suitable due to limitations of performance and lack of full filesystem features. Using `git` on large repo will clearly show why one approach is not ideal :-/

Comment: @user2864740 the `-Persist` option requires a UNC path, so you must use `-Root "\\localhost\c$\Build"` instead of `-Root "C:\Build"`. And **the drive is enumerated in other programs in my PC**, after running that command just go into explorer just like any other network-mapped drives. Only programs running with admin rights might not see it and [needs some workaround](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/mapped-drives-not-available-from-elevated-command). And I don't know why a drive must be mapped just for building. There's no reason doing that

Answer (score 0):

@user2864740:

I was struggling with the same issue and also I noticed that when using **SUBST** some applications weren't able to recognize the new letter.

Then when I was using **net use** command I realized that the system detect my drive as already assigned (but not visible on file explorer). I can imagine that the registry entry was reserving the letter but it was not usable even after using the SUBST command, that seems to work because it was showed in the Windows File Explorer, when drive was usable for accessing files but not for some applications.

In order to solve this issue I had to

- remove the entry from REGISTRY
- restart my computer
- map my drive letter with SUBST

I hope this solution could help you as a workaround.